# How rare is an inside-the-park grand slam home run?

Tags: baseball, trivia, mlb

Michael A. Taylor hit an inside-the-park Grand Slam on Friday, September 8, 2017.  How rare is this event compared to other rare events in baseball?

Answer (score 2):

I can't find stats on this rare event but the last inside-the-park grand slam happened in September 2015. The last one before that was in 1999. So it is a pretty rare event. An inside the park grand slam is usually caused by an outfielder making a mistake of some sort that is **not** considered an error. As a very unusual note, the outfielder involved in the 2015 homer was none other than Michael Taylor. Yep, the same Michael Taylor who hit one recently.

As a side note, in 1956 Roberto Clemente actually did even better. He hit an inside the park grand slam walk off homer.

Comment: What about the list in [this website](https://www.baseball-fever.com/forum/baseball-almanac-baseball-fever-website/baseball-fever-exclusives/175-inside-the-park-grand-slams?threadid=3641) is this correct or not.

Comment: @RamchandraGiri, Well I guess so. That seems like a lot to me especially since there are several in a single year on that list. But the person who made the list claims its comprehensive so I guess it is.  One thing to note about the older dates is that some ball parks didn't have fences back before 1910 I think. So that increased the numbers then.

Comment: Many article that I read mention about the same thing that this becoming rare because of stadium size.

Comment: Good job on finding that list. I googled and found many links but didn't see that one.